# 'gcloud functions deploy' deploys code that cannot listen to Firestore events

Tags: google-cloud-functions

When I try to use a gcloud CLI to deploy a small python script that listens to Firestore events, the script fails to listen to the Firestore events.  If I use the web inline UI or web zip upload, the script actually listens to Firestore events.  The command line doesn't show any errors.

### Deploy script

```
gcloud beta functions deploy print_name \
  --runtime python37 \
  --service-account <myprojectid>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
  --verbosity debug \
  --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create \
  --trigger-resource projects/<myprojectid>/databases/default/documents/Test/{account}
```

### main.py

def print_name(event, context):
    value = event["value"]["fields"]["name"]["stringValue"]
    print("New name: " + str(value))

### gcloud --version

Google Cloud SDK 243.0.0
beta 2019.02.22
bq 2.0.43
core 2019.04.19
gsutil 4.38

### Back to comments

The document is pretty basic (has a name string field).

Any ideas?  I'm curious if the gcloud CLI has a bug.

The inline web UI and zip uploader work great.  I've tried multiple variations of this (e.g. removing 'beta', adding and removing different deploy args).

I'd expect the script to actually listen to Firestore events.

Comment: @MartinZeitler The Firebase CLI can only deploy functions written with the firebase-functions library for node.  No such support is available for python.  python functions must be deployed with gcloud.

Comment: a) One site I found said to use that for beta functionality (which this is).  I've tried both with and without beta.
b) Can `firebase-cli` deploy Python functions?  I wasn't able to find documentation on how to do this (only for JS and TS).  Thoughts?  I spent a while playing with it.

The original instructions came from the following document.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#functions_eventdata-python

Comment: @DougStevenson didn't know that. however, the service account might be at fault - when the script is generally working, but not with this service account.

Comment: I tried playing around with the service account params.  One of the times, I was able to change the service account after a cli-based deploy and it worked.  I wasn't able to reproduce this though.

Comment: I figured it out.  The "default" in trigger-resource needs parentheses around it.

Comment: gcloud beta functions deploy print_name \
  --runtime python37 \
  --service-account <myprojectid>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
  --verbosity debug \
  --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create \
  --trigger-resource "projects/<myprojectid>/databases/(default)/documents/Test/{account}"

Answer (score 1):

The "default" in trigger-resource needs parentheses around it.

```
gcloud beta functions deploy print_name \
--runtime python37 \
--service-account <myprojectid>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
--verbosity debug \
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create \
--trigger-resource "projects/<myprojectid>/databases/(default)/documents/Test/{account}"
```